# How to pass a variable value from powershell back to a batch file which calls it

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script named CHECKlicense.ps1 which compares 2 dates:

```
$enddate   = (Get-Date 2017-3-14).toString("yyyy-M-dd")
$today     = Get-Date -format yyyy-M-dd

if($today -ge $enddate ){
    Write-Output "License is expired"
    $status=1
}else{
    $status=0
}

exit $status
```

and I want to call it from a batch file and return the variable "status". I tried either

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  CHECKlicense.ps1; (Get-Variable status).value"') DO SET VAL=%%i
```

and

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell "&{CHECKlicense.ps1 %* ;exit $LastExitCode}" set code=%errorlevel%
```

But neither work. What am I missing

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you shouldn't compare dates as strings. With the formatting you've used,  10 februari is larger than 1 december. You can test with `'2020-2-10' -gt '2020-12-1'`. Work with real datetimes instead like `$enddate = [DateTime]::ParseExact('2017-3-14', 'yyyy-M-dd', $null)` and `$today = Get-Date`

Answer (score 0):

I ran this from the batch file to get the output with desired status value.

`%errorlevel%` has the value of last executed command... in this case is the powershell return value. You can access and use the variable within the script and in the same command window where you executed the batch file.

```
@echo off 
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell C:\temp\test.ps1
echo This is the code returned by ps1: %errorlevel%
REM You can do other things inside your batch file with %errorlevel%.
```

**Output**

```
License is expired
This is the code returned by ps1: 1
```

Comment: No need to set `%code%` when the `%errorlevel%` variable already exists. just do `echo This is the code returned by ps1: %errorlevel%` and get rid of `set code=%errorlevel%`